# Candy color + flavor probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This one is driving me nuts.

Setup: 
"Your aunt brought you a bag of candy, but it's all mixed up! There are 6 yellow candies, of which 2 are sour and 4 are sweet. 5 blue candies of which 2 are sweet and 3 are sour, and 8 black candies, which are evenly divided between sweet and sour."

Question: 
If you reach in without looking and pull out four candies randomly, what is the probability that the 1st and 4th candies you grab are not the same color or flavor?

It seems like it would be easier to find the total number of combinations, and then subtract the number of combinations where the 1st and 4th match exactly, but I'm not quite sure how to get started.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a vector of the number of candy that are the "same". Without loss of generallity, let:

$$X = \{2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4\}$$

After we draw the first ball we treat each as a [Hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). Because this is an exchangable distribution the order of the draws doesn't matter. So:

$$P(i=1, 2)=\frac{2}{19}\times\frac{1}{18}=\frac{1}{171}$$
$$P(i=3)=\frac{3}{19}\times\frac{2}{18}=\frac{3}{171}$$
$$P(i=4, 5, 6)=\frac{4}{19}\times\frac{3}{18}=\frac{6}{171}$$

Adding them up gives:

$$P=\frac{1}{171}+\frac{1}{171}+\frac{3}{171}+\frac{6}{171}+\frac{23}{171}+\frac{6}{171}=\frac{6}{171}\approx 13.5\%$$